# <?php wp_list_comments(); ?> is it possible to have the full code instead in the comments.php page

Tags: comments

I strongly need to edit some parts of the comments left by the users, I want to add a link to the commenter's author.php page if he/she is a registered user by placing a text link somewhere next to his/her name.
I've this code `<?php wp_list_comments(); ?>` but I wonder if it's possible to have the full code instead to replace it in comments.php
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function replaces the comment author's link with the comment author's profile page,
if the comment author is a registered user. Otherwise, the standard WordPress comment
author link is displayed.

This function is not mine and [has been found googling](http://forum.graphene-theme.com/graphene-support/comment-author-profile#post-3595).

```
function graphene_comment_author_profile_link(){
    /* Get the comment author information */
    global $comment;
    $comment_ID = $comment->user_id;
    $author = get_comment_author( $comment_ID );
    $url    = get_comment_author_url( $comment_ID );

    /* Return the default WordPress comment author link if comment author is not
    a registered user */
    if ($comment_ID == 0){
        if ( empty( $url ) || 'http://' == $url )
            $return = $author;
        else
            $return = "<a href='$url' rel='external nofollow' class='url'>$author</a>";
    } else {
    /* Return the link to the comment author's profile age if otherwise */
        $return = '<a href="'.home_url().'/?author='.$comment_ID.'">'.$author.'</a>';
    }

    return $return;
}
add_filter('get_comment_author_link', 'graphene_comment_author_profile_link');
```

Answer (score 0):

the function [`wp_list_comments()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) has a 'callback' parameter; using a callback function should allow you to edit the code as you described.

for example see in the default theme Twenty Eleven how it is used;

in comments.php:

```
        wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'twentyeleven_comment' ) );
```

the actual functions code is in functions.php, starting with:

```
function twentyeleven_comment( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
```

Comment: Thanks Michael but I found a function that makes the name of the registered user linking to his/her profile without modifying anything else.